# Keep getting a error when I try and sort a list, says "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Tags: python

```
toppings = ["pepperoni", "pineapple", "cheese", "sausage", "olives", "anchovies", "mushrooms"]

prices = [2, 6, 1, 3, 2, 7, 2]
num_two_dollar_slices = prices.count(2)
print(num_two_dollar_slices)

num_pizzas = len(toppings)
print(num_pizzas)
print("We sell "+ str(num_pizzas)+" different kinds of pizza!")

pizza_and_prices =  [2, "pepperoni", 6, "pineapple", 1, "cheese", 3, "sausage", 2, "olives", 7, "anchovies", 2, "mushrooms"]
print(pizza_and_prices)

pizza_and_prices.sort()
print(pizza_and_prices)
```

What do I need to change in order for my list of pizza_and_prices to be sorted into alphabetical order?

Comment: What did you expect that to produce?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It'd be great if you could format your code using [markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet) so that it's more readable for everyone. You want to surround you code with triple backticks (```)

Comment: You can't sort a list that contains a mix of numbers and strings. Make it a list of tuples.

Comment: What you have doesn't make sense.  I could see have a dictionary where the pizza is the key and the price is the value (`{ "pepperoni": 2, "pineapple": 1, ...}`), but that wouldn't need to be sorted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. Do not tell us about your level of experience (it does not change the answer to the question), and do not thank us for our time (we are answering a question that could potentially help someone else *years later* when it is found with a search engine - not having a discussion in the here and now).

Comment: Instead, make sure you **ask a question** - it should begin with a question word like "why" or "how"; it should end with a question mark (`?`); and it should explicitly ask about what you are wondering about. "I'm not sure what to do" [doesn't qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236); "what should I do?" is a little bit closer, but - what should you do *in order to... fill in the blank for us please*?

Comment: If you get an error message, for example, then your question might look something like "why does this error message occur, and how do I fix it?" - but you should try to be more specific than that, by [trying to understand it yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), trying to [figure out the underlying problem with the code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by carefully tracing through the execution of the code, and finally asking about the specific part you don't understand.

Comment: Finally: make sure we can understand the problem by [giving complete but simple code that can cause the problem by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and showing [a complete error message that corresponds to that code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146). When posting code and error messages, try to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) them properly, so that we can see them exactly as you have them.

Comment: The built-in sort can't handle mixed data types. You could write a custom sort or use an intermediate structure that can be sorted then reconstruct the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you have both strings and integers as part of the same list. When python is trying to sort them, it is not able to, because it can't compare strings with int. Hence, you should try using a 2D list. Like this.

```
pizza_and_prices = [[ 6,"pineapple"], [2, "pepperoni"]]
pizza_and_prices.sort(key=lambda pp:pp[0])
```

Comment: This is a relatively good answer, but the problem is we don't know what the OP actually wanted.  It doesn't make sense to sort that list at all.  Why would you sort this by price?  I think we need to get clarification before offering an answer.

Comment: The requirement has been clarified. The problem here is that the OP's data isn't structured as shown in this answer. And yet, bizarrely, this has been accepted as the most useful answer

Comment: The data structure in the question didn't make much sense to me. Because, in it, the prices and pizza names were not tagged to each other. Thus, it made no sense to sort them in that 1-D list. Hence, I suggested the 2-D list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary and then sort the `pizzas` by `prices`:

```
toppings = ["pepperoni", "pineapple", "cheese", "sausage", "olives", "anchovies", "mushrooms"]
prices = [2, 6, 1, 3, 2, 7, 2]
price_list = dict(zip(toppings, prices)) #Create a dictionary
price_list = {k: v for k, v in sorted(price_list.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])} # Sort the dictionary by prices
```

Output:

```
{'cheese': 1, 'pepperoni': 2, 'olives': 2, 'mushrooms': 2, 'sausage': 3, 'pineapple': 6, 'anchovies': 7}
```

Comment: @ArthurKing I knew that but simply sorting the list like that doesn't make sense. Also, if OP wants a link between pizza and prices then why not use a dictionary? You can clearly see how OP accepted the answer which didn't even have the structure of the original data

Comment: @ArthurKing Nevermind my fault *asking someone they can create a dictionary*. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
pizza_and_prices =  [2, "pepperoni", 6, "pineapple", 1, "cheese", 3, "sausage", 2, "olives", 7, "anchovies", 2, "mushrooms"]
p = []
for e in sorted(list(zip(pizza_and_prices[1::2], pizza_and_prices[::2]))):
    p.extend(e[::-1])
pizza_and_prices[:] = p
print(pizza_and_prices)
```

**Output:**

```
[7, 'anchovies', 1, 'cheese', 2, 'mushrooms', 2, 'olives', 2, 'pepperoni', 6, 'pineapple', 3, 'sausage']
```

**Explanation:**

Create a new list of tuples such that each tuple is (description, price). Builtin sort can handle that and will sort it lexicographically (initially). Then unpack that sorted list (of tuples) and rebuild the original list.